# Restore WebView state

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a `WebView` in a `Fragment` and I want to restore my `WebView` state after the `Activity` gets killed and restored. (for example with `do not keep activities` flag)
I'm using the following approach:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
    WebView webView = f.getWebView();
    webView.saveState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and the in `fragment` `onResume`:

```
webView.restoreState(bundle);
```

I was able to go to the url which I also store in `bundle`, but the problem is that my `WebView` contains the `modal window` before it gets destroyed. And I can not restore it to the previous state with that `modal window`. How to restore my `WebView` to the state with `modal window`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it doesn't work. That's the problem.

Comment: Still no answer D: